# I want to show a text value from a button within another div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code, and my intention is when I click one radio button, I want to see the text contained within the button within another div.

This is the jQuery code (which is not working):

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
    $( ".boton" ).click(function() {
      var text = $( this ).text();
      $( ".title" ).val( text );
    });
});
```

And this is the HTML.

This is an example of the radio button:

```
 <input type="radio" class="boton" name="level" id="a" class="grammar1" value="a" style="background:red;" ><span><label for="a" class="grammar1">Grammar explanation</label></span>
```

And this is the div I expect to see the text "Grammar explanation" as a text:

```
<div class="title"></div>
```

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to target immediately following sibling i.e. `SPAN` element as per HTML and `DIV` element doesn't have the value property thus you need to use `.text()`

```
$(".boton").click(function() {
  var text = $(this).next().text();
  $(".title").text(text);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $(".boton").click(function() {
      var text = $(this).next().text();
      $(".title").text(text);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="boton" name="level" id="a" class="grammar1" value="a" style="background:red;"><span><label for="a" class="grammar1">Grammar explanation</label></span>
<br><br><br>
<div class="title"></div>
```